# Javascript function call like somefunction("Hi")("Hello")("How")

Tags: javascript, function, window

Please have a look at this code. I need to show a alert message "mikä on elämän tarkoitus?" using this code

```
window["mikä"]("on")("elämän")("tarkoitus")("?");
```

I need to write a function or piece of code that will show that alert message when I will execute that code.

I have written a function like this:

```
window["mikä"] = function(str){
alert(str);
}
```

which works when I call window"mikä" but if I add more like below in console I see a type error.

```
 window["mikä"]("on")("Hello")("How");
```

My question is would it be valid way to call like below as there is multiple function signs?

```
window["mikä"]("on")("elämän")("tarkoitus")("?")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the functionality you are looking for one way is to write a function which returns a function which returns a function as the others mentioned. That works fine if the number of functions is known before hand. Another way is to use a functional programming technique called [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), which is

> the technique of translating the evaluation of a function that takes multiple arguments (or a tuple of arguments) into evaluating a sequence of functions, each with a single argument (partial application).

You can write your own curry function like this:

```
function curry(func, args_) {
    var self = this;

    self.args = args_ || [];

    return function() {
        var extended_args = [].concat(self.args).concat(Array.slice(arguments));

        if(extended_args.length >= func.length)
            return func.apply(this, extended_args);

        return new curry(func, extended_args);
    };
}
var funcName = "mikä";
window[funcName] = curry(functionstr1, str2, str3, str4) {
    alert(funcName + ' ' + str1 + ' ' + str2 + ' ' + str3 + str4);    
});
window["mikä"]("on")("elämän")("tarkoitus")("?");
```

Here are some resources which can help you if you are interested in learning more about currying / functional programming in JS.

http://kukuruku.co/hub/javascript/an-interesting-task-for-an-interview-currying-and-partial-applicationof-a-function
http://tech.pro/tutorial/2011/functional-javascript-part-4-function-currying
[Reginald Braithwaite's talk in NDC Oslo](http://vimeo.com/97408202)

Comment: Showing error on this line      window[funcName] = curry(functionstr1, str2, str3, str4) {

Comment: What is the error? What browser are you running it on? I have it working in Chrome as you can see from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whzotyqz/). You might try doing it as `window.mikä = ` instead.

Comment: Solved it. In the line    window[funcName] = curry(functionstr1, str2, str3, str4) {    need to add "(" after "function" before "str1" and then add closing bracket ")" after Carly bracket

Comment: Its ok. But thank you so much for sending some reference and helping on this.

Comment: You're welcome. Functional programming is very powerful, and allows you to combine small pieces of functionalities together which leads to a much more readable / maintainable code. If my solution did solve your problem, I would appreciate if you can mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want the return value to be a function as well, so that additional calls on the return value will call the same function. Just add this

```
window["mikä"] = function(str){
  alert(str);
  return window["mikä"];
}
```

EDIT: Misread your question, this will make multiple alert messages. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to nest the function calls

```js
window["mikä"] = function(s1){
    return function(s2) {
        return function(s3) {
            alert(s1 + ' ' + s2 + ' ' + s3);
        }
    }
}

window["mikä"]("on")("elämän")("tarkoitus")("?");
```

As for getting the function name inside the function, there's really no good way to do that, and it should be avoided.